# Windows Phone 7 Silverlight MVVM (and other) frameworks

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, mvvm, windows-phone-7

What are the available mvvm frameworks for WP7 out there today?  Which one(s) would you recommend and why?  Are there other useful frameworks one should consider when starting WP7 silverlight development.

Thanks for posting your experiences so far.

Cheers,
Phil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this [MVVM framework comparer](http://www.japf.fr/2009/11/discover-compare-existing-mvvm-frameworks/). You can filter the frameworks by supported platform (WPF, SL, Windows Phone)

Answer (score 2):

I've had good experiences with [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/), using the [Silverlight Unit Test Framework](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/) for unit testing.

Admittedly I don't have any experience of any other MVVM toolkits, but it seems to work. I'm not using it extensively, and the `ViewModelLocator` pattern hasn't been terribly helpful for me - but I suspect it depends on exactly what you're doing with it.