# MVVM framework recommendations for windows phone 7 development

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone

Can anyone recommend a good and light framework for
 mvvm development on windows phone 7? a list of pros and cons would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Jounce: http://jounce.codeplex.com/
More guidance really this - but I found it useful. It has some really useful debugging and logging elements to it, which makes working with MEF easier especially when it goes wrong.

MVVM Light: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/
I've used MVVM light - its messaging is very simple and easy to use.

UltralightMVVM: http://ultralightmvvm.codeplex.com/

This question may also help you: [Windows Phone 7 Silverlight MVVM (and other) frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033594/windows-phone-7-silverlight-mvvm-and-other-frameworks)

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) - using it it's easier to create ViewModel first and View after. It's created more for software developer then a designer.

Comment: I absolutely love Caliburn.Micro, but I'd stay away from it for WP7 development. Caliburn.Micro is much more comfortable in a VM-first approach like you say, but this approach isn't really feasible in WP7. There are work-arounds but in the end you're better off with a more appropriate MVVM framework.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the comments. I will have it in mind if I start any project for WP7.