# Windows Phone - Create ViewModels within method

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I'm using plain models (entities) for the database and bind them to the view. This works great for me, but now I have a "special" requirement and I think a ViewModel is teh right way.

Currently, I have a group model with many items (1:n). All groups are loaded from the database into a *ObservableCollection<Group>* to display them in a *LongListSelector*. The requirement is to add a second line to the *LongListSelector* with the current number of items within the group. This is not really difficult, but I think it's the right place for a ViewModel.

I must build the ViewModel from the group model object, but where's the right place. Should I create the ViewModel objects for each group model within the *OnNavigatedTo* of the page? In this case, I create the ViewModel object collection on every navigation to the page. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. The first question is what kind of ViewModel classes you will create. I think it is a good convention to create one ViewModel class for every page, for example for the `MainPage` you create a class called `MainPageViewModel`.

This `MainPageViewModel` should take care of loading the data from the database, preferably in its constructor. And because you have to extend your groups with the item count, you can create a ViewModel class for your group as well, called `GroupViewModel`, and the `MainPageViewModel` would have a property called Groups of type `ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>`.

The other interesting question is where to instantiate the `MainPageViewModel`? I see three different approaches:

### 1 Creating the ViewModel directly in XAML

You can create the ViewModel instance in your page and use it directly as the `DataContext` like this:

```
<Page xmlns:local="using:MyApp">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>
...
</Page>
```

I think this is probably the worst solution, because it needs the ViewModel to have a **parameterless constructor** (which is rarely the case), and also it is very **unflexible**, you do not have any control over when the ViewModel-instance will be created.

### 2 Instantiating the ViewModel in code behind

You can simply create the ViewModel-instance in code like this:

```
this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
```

You can do this in the constructor - that way one ViewModel-instance will be created for every Page-instance -, or in the OnNavigatedTo event handler - that way a new ViewModel-instance will be created every time the user navigates to your page.

This approach is somewhat more flexible, but puts code in the code behind of your page, a thing which should be avoided in pure MVVM. Nevertheless, this solution is probably the simplest.

### 3 ViewModelLocator pattern

The last solution is the most complex and needs the most amount of code, but in my opinion is also the best.
You will need a class whose sole purpose will be to create the ViewModel-instances, called the `ViewModelLocator`, which defines properties for the ViewModel of every page:

```
class ViewModelLocator
{
    MainPageViewModel MainPageViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return new MainPageViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

An instance of the locator has to be created as static resource in the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        ...
        <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can simply bind the property of this instance to the DataContext on your page:

```
<Page DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
    ...
</Page>
```

This way every time your page is created, the `MainPageViewModel` property of the ViewModelLocator class will be called. In the above example I implemented the property in a way that it creates a *new instance every time*, but it would be easy to modify it in order to *reuse one instance* for every occasion.

With this pattern, the creation and management of ViewModel instances are **completely decoupled** from the page logic, and this solution is the most flexible and extensible (for example it is really simple to implement design time data with it).

Comment: I already have a MainViewModel which loads the groups from the database and stores them in a `ObservableCollection<Group>`. If I create a GroupViewModel, do I need to create a property for each property of the model that the data is transmitted?

Comment: You definitely can, but it is not necessary. You can put a property `Group WrappedGroup { get; set; }` in your `GroupViewModel`, and then in XAML access the properties of the Group class through that property like this: `{Binding WrappedGroup.SomeProperty}`.

Comment: Okay! When I load the data from the database, I have the simple model group. I loop through all groups and create a GroupViewModel. The same again for the group and items and I create ItemViewModel, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And again, it is not necessary to create an ItemViewModel class for your items, only if you would like to extend them with some kind of extra functionality (computed property, etc.).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! Last question: Should I pass the DataContext (database) from my MainViewModel down to each specific ViewModel or should I keep all database stuff (add to datbase, delete...) in my MainViewModel?

Comment: It's hard to say without more info, but I would probably say neither. Put all your database stuff behind a separate third class (DataService or sth) that does not know your ViewModels, and pass an instance of this class to each of your ViewModels, so they can query the data they need from the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches on where to create your ViewModels. Are you using any of the [popular MVVM frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497377/mvvm-framework-recommendations-for-windows-phone-7-development)? In that case you should follow the instructions and mechanisms used by those frameworks.

If you wish to create a simple VM yourself and bind it, there are different places where you can do it. If you want just one instance of one VM, you could create it in the App.cs class, expose it as public so you can access it from any part of your app. 
If you have multiple VMs which are different and each VM is responsible for one View, you can keep an instance of each VM as a part of a single page, creating it in code only when user navigates to the page. You could also create VM instances in XAML resources and reference them from different parts. It's unclear what exactly is your use case, but these are the common solutions.

Comment: I don't know the right place because I also don't know which ViewModel it is. The *LongListSelector* is on the MainPage, but it shows the list of Group models and I want the number of items within the group as second line of the *LongListSelector*. So is it a MainViewModel or a collection of GroupViewModel and when, where should I store the collection of GroupViewModels?